# UILabel and images in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I would like to show some text with an image. But I would like the text to flow around the image. How can this be done? I've seen I can add views to a label, but I think just adding an image and then text it will not work. Can you point me to the right way please?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I would like the text to flow around the image."  Do you mean, as if the text is orbiting around some image or do you mean that it's just on the outer edges of the image?

Comment: So on the top left corner I will have an image and on the right side I would like the text appear and under the image also like to appear the text. I hope you understand.

Comment: You might be better off drawing a quick picture of what you mean and updating your original question with it.  What you are describing does not sound like it can be done with a standard library object.

Comment: lol the image has been megaupload'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to create a UI Label for the side of the image, then another UI label below the image - then calculate the height of the first label a word at a time from your original text, once you have gone past the height of the UIImageView put the rest of the text in the bottom UILabel.

If you would like some example code, please email me at kendall.gelner AT kigisoftware.com (I tried to look for a way to email or DM you, but could not find one on this site).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample image, this would be a custom object that you would have to create as a subclass of `UIImage` ..or you could go the easier route just make it as a view in Interface Builder that you add as a subview.

An example of subclassing `UIImage` would be like creating a helper method:

```
@interface UIImage (Labels)
- (UIImage*)toSize:(CGSize)size withLabel:(NSString *)label1 andSecondLabel:(NSString *)label2;
@end
```

but you would have to then implement drawing it all by yourself.

Instead, I would probably say go the route of creating a view in Interface Builder that has:

> (1) UIImageView
>
> (6) UILabels

that you can use as a subview and then you'd set them to whatever values like normal in code.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but [Three20](http://three20.info/overview#UI) is the most powerful project that I have ever seen in Iphone to support text and stylesheet. You may want to take a look